# "This feature is not yet enabled. Press Next to activate it.", but pressing" Next" does not Activate it. In netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I can't create a New Project of any kind. I get this error message, "This feature is not yet enabled. Press Next to activate it.", but pressing" Next" does not Activate it.

Comment: now you will not face that problem with new versions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Overview

---

I ran into this same exact issue after installing Netbeans on a fresh Ubuntu system.  Turns out I selected all the defaults when I installed Netbeans, and the defaults happened to be incorrect.

For me, I fixed it by altering a line in the file `netbeans.conf`.  Assuming you already have the Java Developer's Kit (JDK) installed, the following steps should fix the issue.

## Solution

---

1. Identify the JDK's home folder.  If you have the JAVA_HOME environment variable set, execute this from a terminal: 
   `env | grep JAVA_HOME`

If the JAVA_HOME variable isn't set, you can execute: `whereis java`

You'll need to note the installation directory of the java executable.  On my system executing `whereis java` returns the following:

```
username@hostname$ whereis java<BR>
java: /usr/bin/java /usr/lib/java /usr/share/java /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
```

Using the information above, my JAVA_HOME directory is: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle`
To confirm you've noted the correct JAVA_HOME directory, using terminal change directory there and execute the command:

```
ls -la
```

If you have the JDK installed and you've located the correct directory, you should see two folders in the listing:

```
include/
lib/
```

2. Locate the `netbeans.conf` file by executing the following in terminal:

`username@hostname$ sudo find / -name netbeans.conf`

3. Edit the `netbeans.conf` file and change the path of the `netbeans_jdkhome` variable to the JAVA_HOME directory (identified in step 1).

Note: you might need to edit the `netbeans.conf` file using sudo.  For example you could enter in a terminal:
`sudo gedit <netbeans_install_directory>/etc/netbeans.conf`

## Conclusion

---

If you located all of the correct directories and have the JDK installed, this should fix the issue.  You'll need to restart Netbeans after you complete the steps.  And it should tell you one last time it needs to update a few plugins, but this time it should locate them and download the required Java plugins.

A couple of other things to note, if the solution worked you should see a coffee icon in the `Projects` tab of Netbeans (see screenshot below).  And if you click on the menu `Tools -> Options -> Java -> Java Debugger` in Netbeans, you should no longer see the `Activate` button all by itself.  Instead, you should see several fields and options you can select from, to configure the Java Debugger.

[image: Coffee icon in Netbeans]

Answer (score 3):

The Java SE Environment plug-in is not activated:

```
Tools > Plugins > Installed >
```

Now you need to select Java SE and press "Activate"

Worked for me.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to resolve this error on a Linux environment is to specify the location of your jdk by using the jdkhome parameter on the command line

```
./netbeans --jdkhome <path to jdk>
```

Answer (score 0):

**For a simple Java SE application follow these steps:**

1. File
2. New Project
3. In categories choose Java with Maven
4. Java Application
5. Click Next and wait for the feature activation

**Note 1:**
Be sure that your machine is connected to the internet.

**Note 2:**
This worked for my Apache NetBeans IDE 15 in Windows 10.